# Where can I find a tool to set a non-resizable window to a size larger than the native resolution?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I'm trying to play a game with a locked resolution which is too large to properly fit in the window. Unfortunately, the window is non-resizable, and the resolution the game runs in is larger than my native resolution.

Is there a tool which would allow me to:

1. Make the window resizable, and
2. Make the size of the window larger than my native resolution?

I already tried a few tools for making non-resizable windows resizable, but none of them can make the window bigger than the native resolution.

Here are the specific details, in case they're necessary: The game runs in 1440x900. My native resolution is 1280x1024.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This problem has now been solved.

For anyone else with a similar problem, here's what I used:

https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/Infinite-Screen.shtml

1. Download and install Infinite Screen 1.72 from the link above.
2. Start Infinite Screen.
3. Go to the "Oversize" tab.
4. Open the window that you want to make bigger.
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> back to Infinite Screen.
6. Click "Reload List."
7. Find the window you want to make bigger.
8. Click the "4ever" checkbox.
9. Increase the height/width as desired.

The window should now be the desired size, even if that is larger than your native resolution.